# Rails :before_create callback not working for my Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I'm trying to do the following in my Rails 3 model:

```
require 'securerandom'

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :key
  before_create :generate_key

  private

  def generate_key
    self.key = SecureRandom.hex(3)
  end

end
```

However when I create a Contest, all the fields in my table appear to be correct except the key which remains nil in my DB.

**More Info:**

In my rails server log, I see the following when I create a contest through my "create contest form"

```
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "contests" ("category", "created_at", "description", "key", "price", "status", "time", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["category", "camisas"], ["created_at", Wed, 15 Feb 2012 18:57:16 UTC +00:00], ["description", "test_description"], ["key", nil], ["price", 111], ["status", "In process"], ["time", "2sem"], ["title", "test_contest"], ["updated_at", Wed, 15 Feb 2012 18:57:16 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 5]]
```

Note the ["key", nil]

But that should be correct right?, I would guess that the key will be added by the Contest.rb :before_create callback?

Maybe I'm miss-using SecureRandom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `attr_accessor`? This method is actually going to be defining both a setter and getter method for a key, keeping track of a virtual attribute.

Perhaps you meant to use `attr_accessible`, but even then that is unnecessary, because you're setting the attribute directly.

Really, you don't need either `attr_accessor :key` or `attr_accessible :key` in your model at all if you're just setting it like this. Remove the `attr_accessor` and it will work.

Comment: Yeah I missed that one. I removed :attr_accessor and still doesn't work though :(

Comment: I restarted the server and it worked. Weird, because I already tried your solution some minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write `attr_accessible <list accessible params>` for example:

`attr_accessible :key, :category`